# Accessing Workgroup Shared Folder from Domain

Tags: networking, windows-xp, domain, scripting, workgroup

I have a **domain** and a **workgroup**. My users are supposed to **upload files on regular basis to several shared folders on the workgroup.**

I have difficulty accessing the workgroup shared folders without firstly mapping them to a drive letter. I do not need (neither want) to create separate network drives for say 15 different workgroup folders (they are on separate PCS).

Is there a way how to **create a shortcut to shared workgroup folder** so that the **destination workgroup folder will open on clicking it?**

*Here are the key remarks:*

- The OS used: Windows XP SP3
- The 15 shared workgroup folders are on different PCs
- Ideally, I wish to access them without username and password, if possible
- If the workgroup shared folders can not be accessed without username and password, I will create identcal user and very simple password for all of them, but i wish to have them used without asking users to enter it
- I wish to accomplish this on clicking one file (shortcut to the shared folder or .bat script)
- After the user clicks the file, I wish to have open the desired location
- The solution can be achieved with simple script
- I do not wish to use: USE NET and map separate drive for every location

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, you can net use without a drive letter and then just open the path after you authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the built-in Guest account and set a blank password.

Set share and ntfs permissions on the share and folder for the Guest account.

Make a simple shortcut to the share and drop it on the users desktop.

Comment: @Molotoch, thanks for your reply. This is the way, i would expect it to work. However, during the shortcut creation, when I type the hostname or the IP Address, I always get: **"the file \\IP Addr\Fodder" cannot be found.** I am sure, I have configured both, Share and NTFS permissions for Guest and that I can Ping the target PC.

Comment: @Molotoch: the only way, I was able to achieve this is calling **NET USE \\hostname\folder /user:myUser myPSW** However, in this case, I have to manually click on the shortcut, and that requires two steps. I  look for a slingle click solution, like the above described.

Comment: Could you perhaps make that a shortcut to a .cmd containing the `net use` and a call to `explorer.exe \\hostname\folder` which would mount and open said share in a single click?

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori What happens if you use the hostname when you create the shortcut, same error message? Try both with and without an ending backslash \

Comment: @Molotch: Yes, I tried multiple variations. Exactly, within the **Create Shortcut** window, in the first step I am supposed to enter the location. After entring it, the system waits cca 30 seconds and then say the above error: **"The Directory cannot be found"**. That is basically all, and I may not go further within the process.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori Sounds like a Windows XP issue. Try browsing to the folder in explorer using the Entire Network node and right click "create shortcut" on the folder.

Comment: @Molotch: Mabe, its just not meant to be possible, that Domain PCs would see Workgroup PCs? Well, i will keep reading. Thank you for your kind help. Take care.

Comment: Did you try disabling the Windows Firewall on the workgroup PCs?